# Routing error in Laravel resulting in: Call to undefined method ReflectionUnionType::getName()

Tags: php, laravel, routes, reflection

Currently, I am writing tests for my Laravel application. However, one test fails and I don't know why or how to solve it. I am running on Laravel 10 and PHP 8.2.3.

I have products and posts. Both models are morphed to the table and model comments because a user can write a comment under a product and under a post.

This is my route for the `index` function of the comments for either a product or a post with a given `id`:

```
Route::get('/comments/{commentableType}/{commentableId}', [CommentController::class, 'index'])->name('comments.index');
```

In the following, you will see my `RouteServiceProvider`. Here you can see, how I have binded the `commentableType` and `commentableId`. The strange thing now is, when I `dd` the line `(new $model)->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();` the correct product or post for the given `id`is being returned. Therefore, the route binding should be correct, I guess.

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api/v1')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->domain(config('app.domain'))
                ->group(base_path('routes/api/comment.php'));
        });

        // Defines a pattern for categoryType
        Route::pattern('categoryType', 'product|post');

        // Returns the id of the product or post
        Route::bind('commentableId', function ($id) {
            $type = app()->request->route('commentableType');
            $models = ['product' => Product::class, 'post' => Post::class];
            $model = $models[$type];
            return (new $model)->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        });
    }
}
```

This is my `CommentController@index` function:

```
public function index(IndexCommentRequest $request, String $commentableType, Product | Post $commentableModel): JsonResponse
{
    $comments = $request->perform($commentableType, $commentableModel);

    return $this->successWithPayload(new CommentResource($comments));
}
```

And this is my `IndexCommentRequest` file

```
class IndexCommentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'sorting' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'in:popular,discussed,newest',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function perform(String $commentableType, Product | Post $commentableModel): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        return $commentableModel->comments($this->input('sorting'))
            ->with('children')
            ->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why the following error is being thrown. I have already tried to google it but found no solution... I am so confused that the correct model is being found and therefore also returned but then the following error is being thrown:

```
array:5 [ // tests/Feature/Http/CommentController/IndexCommentTest.php:30
  "message" => "Call to undefined method ReflectionUnionType::getName()"
  "exception" => "Error"
  "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Reflector.php"
  "line" => 151
  "trace" => array:62 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php"
      "line" => 31
      "function" => "isParameterBackedEnumWithStringBackingType"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Support\Reflector"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "function" => "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php"
      "line" => 31
      "function" => "array_filter"
    ]
    3 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php"
      "line" => 533
      "function" => "fromAction"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
    4 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ImplicitRouteBinding.php"
      "line" => 80
      "function" => "signatureParameters"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Route"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    5 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ImplicitRouteBinding.php"
      "line" => 28
      "function" => "resolveBackedEnumsForRoute"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
    6 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 947
      "function" => "resolveForRoute"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
    7 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php"
      "line" => 41
      "function" => "substituteImplicitBindings"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    8 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    9 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php"
      "line" => 126
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    10 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php"
      "line" => 92
      "function" => "handleRequest"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    11 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php"
      "line" => 54
      "function" => "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    12 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    13 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/app/Http/Middleware/JsonResponse.php"
      "line" => 20
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    14 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "App\Http\Middleware\JsonResponse"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    15 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 116
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    16 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 797
      "function" => "then"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    17 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 776
      "function" => "runRouteWithinStack"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    18 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 740
      "function" => "runRoute"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    19 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      "line" => 729
      "function" => "dispatchToRoute"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    20 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      "line" => 200
      "function" => "dispatch"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    21 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 141
      "function" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    22 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php"
      "line" => 21
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    23 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php"
      "line" => 31
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    24 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    25 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php"
      "line" => 21
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    26 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php"
      "line" => 40
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    27 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    28 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php"
      "line" => 27
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    29 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    30 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php"
      "line" => 86
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    31 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    32 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php"
      "line" => 62
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    33 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    34 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php"
      "line" => 39
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    35 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 180
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    36 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      "line" => 116
      "function" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    37 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      "line" => 175
      "function" => "then"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    38 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      "line" => 144
      "function" => "sendRequestThroughRouter"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    39 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php"
      "line" => 563
      "function" => "handle"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    40 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php"
      "line" => 324
      "function" => "call"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    41 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/tests/Feature/Http/CommentController/IndexCommentTest.php"
      "line" => 24
      "function" => "get"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    42 => array:3 [
      "function" => "Tests\Feature\Http\CommentController\{closure}"
      "class" => "P\Tests\Feature\Http\CommentController\IndexCommentTest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    43 => array:3 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/src/Factories/TestCaseFactory.php"
      "line" => 151
      "function" => "call_user_func"
    ]
    44 => array:3 [
      "function" => "Pest\Factories\{closure}"
      "class" => "P\Tests\Feature\Http\CommentController\IndexCommentTest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    45 => array:3 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/src/Concerns/Testable.php"
      "line" => 301
      "function" => "call_user_func_array"
    ]
    46 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/src/Support/ExceptionTrace.php"
      "line" => 29
      "function" => "Pest\Concerns\{closure}"
      "class" => "P\Tests\Feature\Http\CommentController\IndexCommentTest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    47 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/src/Concerns/Testable.php"
      "line" => 300
      "function" => "ensure"
      "class" => "Pest\Support\ExceptionTrace"
      "type" => "::"
    ]
    48 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/src/Concerns/Testable.php"
      "line" => 278
      "function" => "__callClosure"
      "class" => "P\Tests\Feature\Http\CommentController\IndexCommentTest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    49 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 1608
      "function" => "__test"
      "class" => "P\Tests\Feature\Http\CommentController\IndexCommentTest"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    50 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 173
      "function" => "runTest"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    51 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 1214
      "function" => "runTest"
      "class" => "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    52 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php"
      "line" => 728
      "function" => "runBare"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    53 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      "line" => 964
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    54 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php"
      "line" => 684
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    55 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php"
      "line" => 684
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    56 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php"
      "line" => 653
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    57 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php"
      "line" => 144
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    58 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/src/Console/Command.php"
      "line" => 119
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    59 => array:5 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/bin/pest"
      "line" => 62
      "function" => "run"
      "class" => "Pest\Console\Command"
      "type" => "->"
    ]
    60 => array:3 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/pestphp/pest/bin/pest"
      "line" => 63
      "function" => "{closure}"
    ]
    61 => array:3 [
      "file" => "/Users/jt/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dbb/vendor/bin/pest"
      "line" => 120
      "function" => "include"
    ]
  ]
]
```

This is my Pest test function but I get this error also without Pest or without PHPUnit when trying to make a normal API call to this route. Therefore, it has nothing to do with my testing code:

```
it('displays the first 10 comments for a given commentable model with children', function () {
    $product = Product::factory()->create();

    $comments = Comment::factory()->count(15)->create([
        'commentable_type' => Product::class,
        'commentable_id' => $product->id,
    ]);

    $comments->each(function ($comment) {
        Comment::factory()->count(2)->create([
            'parent_id' => $comment->id,
        ]);
    });

    $response = $this->get(route('comments.index', [
        'commentableType' => 'product',
        'commentableId' => $product->id,
        'sorting' => 'newest',
    ]));

    dd($response->json());
});
```

I am very thankful for every answer to help me solve this problem!

Comment: This is why it is so important to use the same names always... I saw so many PHP posts and code that failed just because of not using the same name... I don't understand why devsndo that... You will always have errors in general if you continue to do this, intentionally or by mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI segment name should be the same to the argument of controller method. In route URI, you use **commentableId** but in controller method, you use `$commentableModel`. So try changing the name of argument to $commentableId:

```
public function index(IndexCommentRequest $request, String $commentableType, Product | Post $commentableId): JsonResponse
{
    $comments = $request->perform($commentableType, $commentableModel);

    return $this->successWithPayload(new CommentResource($comments));
}
```

If it doesn't work neither, try removing strict type Product | Post:

```
  public function index(IndexCommentRequest $request, String $commentableType, $commentableId): JsonResponse
    {
        $comments = $request->perform($commentableType, $commentableModel);
    
        return $this->successWithPayload(new CommentResource($comments));
    }
```